# Are evolutionary algorithms such as PSO, used in Deep learning for finding optimal weights?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

All I have seen so far, e.g in convnets is that every one is using Xavier for initialization or random Gaussian distribution. I could not have found any article that like in Artificial neural networks, use algorithms such as GA,PSO, etc to find optimal weights for layers.
Are they not applicable in this field due to the number of parameters? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're right, they are not very suitable for such a huge number of parameters.

Comment: Is it not possible  to train a miniature version of a network with tiny number  of parameters this way and then apply the weights through out the actual net ? will this work?

Comment: Yes, but you need keep in mind that NN try to minimize the unknown function, whether other algorithm try to maximize it. So you probably would need to make some small modifications to make them work properly.

Comment: @itdxer: Thank you verymuch, but I didnt get that! Would you elaborate more on this?